# Delivery Optimization process - takes all of the RAM

Tags: memory, windows-11, svchost

My apps were crashing because of out of memory problem, so I started to look for a cause and it was caused by the "Delivery Optimization" service. It was taking all of the free memory.

I have no computers on my LAN, that would use this service. I have also checked the "Delivery Optimization activity monitor" in Windows settings and it says, that since last month, it only downloaded from the Microsoft. No other downloads/uploads.

After manually stopping the service (from "services.msc" menu), the memory went from 16GB/16GB to ~6GB/16GB.

I have turned off the "Allow downloads from other PCs" in Windows menu, but didn't help. I have also tried to disable the service, but access is denied. So the process (svchost.exe) eventually starts again. The process is using the network (downloads something with 3Mbps) and slowly starting to fill up the RAM again, until it crashes. In task manager, I can't even see the "Command Line" of the process - it's empty - I can only see the "svchost.exe" and that it's part of the Delivery Optimization service.

[image]

By running "netstat" cmd, I can see the process has ~100 of connections to just **two** internet IPs on port 80

[image]

Any ideas what migh be happening?

UPDATE

According to Fiddler, this service is trying to download something from xboxlive.com. However it's sending the same requests over and over:
[image]

Comment: Does [How to Turn Off Delivery Optimization on Windows 11](https://www.howtogeek.com/793154/turn-off-delivery-optimization-windows-11/) answer your question?

Comment: No, my question is not how to turn it off. Question is why this service is taking ~10GB of RAM. And by the way, I have turned the "Allow downloads from other PCs" off as is suggested in your link.

Comment: @Ramhound I was hoping that this might be some common issue/bug. Otherwise I am scared that it might be some malware. I am using Windows 11 Pro 22H2 64 bit - latest updates.

Comment: It’s not a Windows bug. It could be a device driver bug. However, you haven’t provided any information, to even make that a potential explanation (only mentioning it because I have potentially seen it before with my own hardware)

Comment: Didn't think there may be connection to hardware.

MB: MSI B450-A PRO MAX, CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3700x, GPU: GTX 1080 TI (Drivers maintaned by nvidia experience), RAM: 2x 8GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what was the root cause of this problem, but I have found a solution.

In

```
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.GamingServices_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\UserDataCache\
```

there were folders with `appmanifest.xml` files in it containing info about the packages, that the Delivery Optimization service was trying to download.

I searched for the name of the folder `F6E35395-C5D3-4598-9763-30658558E6B4` inside the registries and found+deleted entries referring to that string from `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\GamingServices`, then deleted the cache folder itself, killed the "Gaming Services" service and restarted. After this, problem is not occurring anymore.